# Определение расстояния до нескольких координат в background

Tags: java, android, алгоритм, sqlite

Имеется БД в приложении, которая хранит в себе объекты с координатами `latitude` и `longitude`. Объектов много, в районе тысячи, а то и больше. Также имеем своё текущее местоположение.

Стоит следующая задача: В приложении задаем радиус, к примеру 500м, после чего стартуем сервис, который должен следить, какие объекты попадают в установленный диапазон, следить всегда, по мере движения пользователя. И если новый объект из БД находится в радиусе, то отображать нотификацию.

Проблема не в получении координат, не в написании службы, а проблема с алгоритмом трекания координат объектов из БД. Как лучше стоит реализовать логику? Неужели придется обращаться каждые n-секунд к базе и по всем объектам расчитывать расстояние? Буду рад любым советам.

Comment: насколько я понял, то вы искал что-то подобное. https://habrahabr.ru/post/210162/ далее уже можно найти уроки по его использованию

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас ознакомлюсь

Comment: Геофенсы это совершенно другая разработка, хотя ощущение что автор делает что-то подобное, ну там низкоуровневый сервис у них работает , что без гпс и инета определяет радиус покрытия. В чем сложность после задания радиуса (фильтра) выгружать данные из Бд и складывать как вам угодно, ну типо кеширования. Это же очень лёгкая операция с координатами, после при любом запросе делать фильтрацию по кешированием данным, по моему здесь все очевидно.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Я просто искал вариант не обращаться к БД с запросом каждые n-секунд, или каждые n-метров, понятно что по фильтрам, а хотел использовать какой-нибудь callback, который бы сообщал, что мы вошли в зону новой точки. Но на что его вешать, варианта не придумал.

Answer (score 1):

По поводу расчета расстояний до объектов - я бы посмотрел в сторону postgres с gist-индексами по типу circle. Тогда запрос не будет считать все расстояния и выполнится довольно быстро.

По поводу обращения к БД каждые n секунд - если отслеживается перемещение, то можно обращаться каждые, например, 100 м, но не чаще, чем раз в n секунд. Это должно снизить количество обращений.

Comment: Плюсанул ответ. Посыл понятен.